# jQuery: clone input field without losing keyCode functionality

Tags: javascript, jquery

Been trying to build jQuery support into a text input where pressing return duplicates the div container into the space right below it. What I can't figure out is how to focus on the input field inside the newly-created div automatically, and, even more frustrating, why that new input field loses the functionality to duplicate. In other words, pressing return only duplicates if you are in the originally-created input field.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    textboxes = $("input.data-entry");
        if ($.browser.mozilla) {
        $(textboxes).keypress (checkForAction);
        } 
        else {
        $(textboxes).keydown (checkForAction);
        }
 });

function checkForAction (event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        $(this).clone().val('').appendTo('#form_container');
        return false;
}
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="form_container">   
        <input name="firstrow" type="text" class="data-entry">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

use `.clone(true)` to copy event handlers. see the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(textboxes).live('keypress', function(checkForAction));
```